# Macro argument is not expanded instead gives compiler error - c preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
/* file.c */

#define PCH_LPC_RCBA_BASE_ADDRESS           0xFED1C000
#define READ_MEM8 (MemAddr)                 MmioRead8 (MemAddr)
#define READ_MEM8_RCRB (wReg)               READ_MEM8 (PCH_LPC_RCBA_BASE_ADDRESS | wReg)


UINT8 IoValue = READ_MEM8_RCRB (0x10);
```

Got a compiler error
error C2065: 'wReg' : undeclared identifier

wReg did not get substituted with 0x10. what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's a standard Rule not to leave blank between Macro Template and It's Argument.
Do not give space between `READ_MEM8_RCRB` and `(wReg)` as:

1. `wReg` will be part of Macro Expansion.
2. It may result in Improper Result or in your case Compile Time Error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space

i.e.

```
#define PCH_LPC_RCBA_BASE_ADDRESS           0xFED1C000
#define READ_MEM8(MemAddr)                 MmioRead8 (MemAddr)
#define READ_MEM8_RCRB(wReg)               READ_MEM8(PCH_LPC_RCBA_BASE_ADDRESS | wReg)
```